# Is it possible to monitor visited websites from router?

Tags: router, browsing

Is it possible to retrieve the browsing history of a device from the router itself? Or at least monitor currently visited website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you have a consumer grade router, and you have not provided any information regarding make/model, etc.  So, no idea if your particular device has this functionality - but typically cheap/ISP issued consumer grade routers do not have this sort of feature available.

If you want this sort of functionality, you need to go with something like PFSense which sits between your router and your LAN.  You can then use PFSense to do a whole stack of really cool things including look at all traffic moving through it.